# figuring out my grandsons name!

Tags: cipher

Given:

> RCK = THE
>  TKRRKLG = LETTERS
>  SO = IN
>  HJHI = BABY
>  OZQHKL
>   = NUMBER
>  RDB'G = TWO'S
>  OJQK = NAME
>  JLK = ARE
>
> YKXRKICRQAKLGLJFKTSK = _E_TEYHTM_ERSRA_ELIE ( DESCHAMP is BABY'S LAST NAME)

Find the baby's first name and middle name.

Comment: Last string of letters beginning with y ending with k are the baby's first, middle and last name all jumbled, .....hint....baby's last name will be Deschamp

Answer (score 5):

I substituted letters in Deschamp that are missing from the substitutions already performed in your question. That left one letter unknown. Removed the letters in Deschamp and ran it through an anagram solver to get

> Pieter Teyler

Comment: Can't start with P. The four unknown letters are AFXY (all different) and only one of them is P (already taken by DESCHAMP). It could be any of FGJKQVZ.